# Can the component AV cable and the HDMI cable mirror third party apps on TV?

Tags: hdmi, ipad

So I heard of the following:

1) the component AV cable and the HDMI cable for iPad 1 cannot show the game play (3rd party apps) on TV.  Those 2 cables can only show movies and photos -- that's it.

2) The HDMI cable for iPad 2 can do 100%, exact mirroring NO MATTER WHAT THE APP IS.  Whatever shows on iPad 2's screen, it will show.

Are the above 2 facts true?  And what about Component AV cables for iPad 2, can it do 100% mirroring or is it limited to movies and photos?  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 1 is exactly true, unless the developer chose to output the gameplay through the cable. A few games do this, but most do not.

Number 2 is exactly true.

<s>On your last question, I'm not 100% certain and haven't tried it (I don't have the component cables). Video mirroring from the iPad 2 [works with the VGA adapter](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/03/19/in_depth_review_apples_ipad_2_running_ios_4_3.html&page=3), so it would likely work with the component cables, but I can't guarantee it.</s>

**Edit:** Looking at [the specs on Apple's site](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/) under *TV & Video*, it seems pretty clear that component out work with the apps that do video out, but not for mirroring.

Answer (score 2):

To add a little bit more to Matthew's answer- the [Apple Digital AV Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC953ZM/A?fnode=MTc0MjU4NjE&mco=MTcyMTgxODY) will work on the iPad 1 to output video and audio from apps like Videos, Youtube, Netflix, etc... but will not work for full mirroring. That is strictly an iPad2+Digital AV Adapter thing. The outputting of both the audio and video through the HDMI cable is pretty cool though, one less cable to jack in.